# Netbeans doesnt recognize class in the same package

Tags: java, netbeans, libgdx, package

i am creating a little game with libgdx framework and netbeans 8. I have all java classes in a single package that match with the directory structure.
The problem is that i cant import or isntantiate classes, for example:

```
package com.myfolder.folder2;

import ...
public class myclass1{

private myclass2 mc2;
etc...
}
```

In this case myclass2 is public and is inside the package but netbeans complains "cannot find symbol". 
If i try with alt+enter, netbeans says "Create class myclass2 in package com.myfolder.folder2" or the same like an inner class. If i press the first option, netbeans create a class in the package with the file name myclass2_1 (becouse myclass2 exists!), and myclass1 doesnt recognize the new class.
If i try to import the class:

```
import com.myfolder.folder2.myclass2;
```

It gives me the same error, and in fact the code completion tool only gives me one crazy option in the import sentence:

```
import com.myfolder.folder2.myclass1;
```

Import the same class.

What can i do? I never have these problems using netbeans.

PD: Sorry for my english :)

Comment: The file exists but it seems class2 has compile problems. Thats the reason it can't be imported. Also you should follow the convention of naming your classes with starting capital. **MyClass1**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class inside the same package like this:
`ClassName classVariableName = new ClassName();`

Then when you want to run something from the class you would put

`classVariableName.MethodThatIWantToRun();`

Or if you want to access a property from that method you would access it in a very similar way:

`classVarabileName.PropertyIWantToAccess`

Example:

You have one class with a property you want to access:

```
class MyClass {
    public int MyProperty = 5;
}
```

You access it in this class:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(myClass.MyProperty);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work than you might have some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error with one of my class package definition:

```
public class DesktopLauncher{

public static void main(String... args){
LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
.
.
.
new LwjglApplication(new MyClass, config);
}
}
```

It was in MyClass, becouse i copied a snippet from an older project, and accidentally copied the older package.

Answer (score 0):

### NetBeans is not smart enough,

**Solution**: just declare the package name in all classes, example:

**Class A:**

```
package test;
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
       ClassB.myFunctionB();
    }    
}
```

**Class B:**

```
package test;
public class ClassB {
    public static void myFunctionB () {            
    System.out.print("I am ClassB!");
    }    
}
```